# How to access server address

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed HospitalRun On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/linuxbiekaisar/0ac1e5fed3be4142f66acac420e672ed). Now it tells me the server address but when I visit it on chrome browser the site is not reachable. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: That `server address` is saying `localhost`. That won't work from any other box. Try checking the IP in the server with `ip addr show`.

Comment: @eftshift0 the ip addr is `134.103.214.97`. How should I proceed now?

Comment: I guess now you could browse to `http://that-ip:4000` (consider removing the comment with the IP. quite frankly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install nginx on ubuntu and pass  4000 port in proxy .

```
server {
          client_max_body_size 20M;

        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name ;
        location / {

          proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    client_body_timeout 3000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    client_max_body_size 128m;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
}
}
```

then its works on VM public ip .

else you have to create a domain in nginx and then able to pass proxy .